# In the comics is Two-face's coin a regular coin?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

In Christopher Nolan's The Dark Knight, Harvey Dent starts off with a double headed coin, which then gets turned into having two different sides when he becomes Two-face.

Is this the same in the comics?

Is Two-face's coin a regular coin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the original [Detective Comics #66](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Detective_Comics_Vol_1_66), after becoming hideously scarred, Two-Face disfigured a two-headed silver dollar with his knife. The coin itself originally belonged to Vincent "The Boss" Maroni and is usually shown as having scratches on the side with either Lady Liberty or, in later serials, Lady Gotham.

[image]

This theme is continued in future comic serials such as Nightwing

[image]

And the rebooted Detective Comics

[image]

Comment: Apropos of nothing, in the animated series it's a [liberty half-dollar](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/File:Two-Face_Coin_DCAU_01.jpg)

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that a liberty head dollar does not have heads on both sides. Unless you count the eagle's head, maybe? I had to google that up, since I don't really know coins. I know it's standard today to have very different front/back, but don't know how long that has been in effect in the US (or anywhere else).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - I've edited accordingly. Apparently it's a "two-headed Silver Dollar", not a liberty dollar.

Answer (score 1):

Two Face's coin would likely have been a "Peace Dollar," the most common dollar coin in circulation at the time of his origin in 1942. Minted from 1921 to 1928, and again from 1934 to 1935, the Peace Dollar had the head of Liberty on the obverse, and an American Bald Eagle perched on a rock over the word "Peace" on the reverse. They are 90% silver and 10% copper. Therefore, the "lucky" two-headed dollar would have to have been a special novelty piece, as no such coin was ever issued. Peace dollars are very beautiful and highly collectible today. Personally, I like the idea of Two Face's coin being a regular Peace dollar with the obverse defaced and the reverse pristine, but that's just me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question wasn't about what specifically the coin originally was, it was if the movie matched the comic (yes) and if it was a real coin (no).  The comic clearly describes a coin with a face on each side, so it isn't a regularly minted coin.  If you have another comic you can show having a different representation of Two-face's coin, you should include that detail.